# Generate a New Guid into a Textbox area using a button. (C#)

Tags: c#

Looking for help.
I have a form which generates fields into a Class extends groupbox.
I am creating a button to clear and then generate a new GUID into a text box but I can seem to access my textbox which has been creating in the Initialize method.

I created a list to store input.

```
private List<InputSetItem> _inputSetItems = new List<InputSetItem>();
```

This is where the textbox is created:

```
public void initialize()
        {

            //balanceIdentifier
            var balanceIdentifierSet = InputGenerator.GenerateInputControl(this, typeof(Guid), "BalanceIdentifier");
            Controls.Add(balanceIdentifierSet.Label);
            Controls.Add(balanceIdentifierSet.Input);
            balanceIdentifierSet.Label.Left = 820;
            balanceIdentifierSet.Input.Left = 1050;
            balanceIdentifierSet.Input.Width = 400;
            balanceIdentifierSet.Label.Top = 20;
            balanceIdentifierSet.Input.Top = 20;
            _inputSetItems.Add(balanceIdentifierSet);

            // btn_Guid
            this.btn_Guid.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            this.btn_Guid.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.btn_Guid.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btn_Guid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1455, 19);
            this.btn_Guid.Name = "btn_Guid";
            this.btn_Guid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 26);
            this.btn_Guid.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btn_Guid.Text = "GENERATE";
            this.btn_Guid.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btn_Guid.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            this.btn_Guid.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // Give the button a flat appearance.
            this.btn_Guid.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Controls.Add(btn_Guid);
            this.btn_Guid.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.generateRandomGuid);
        }
```

This is the UI

[image]

This is my Generate Method, I cant wrap my head around accesses and updating this textBox

```
private void generateRandomGuid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var delBal = new InputSetItem();
        Guid randomGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        //delBal.btn_Guid.Input = randomGuid.ToString();
        //delBal.Input.Text;

    }
```

Comment: By doing this `delBal.btn_Guid.Input = randomGuid.ToString();` you are trying to modify the Button's property. You should set the value of the text box to the GUID.

Comment: `yourTextBox.Text = randomGuid.ToString();`

Comment: @Cid I tried this, Because im generating my input box into balanceIdentifierSet , i need a way to access the balanceIdentifierSet.Input.Text and this is what im struggle with XD

Comment: You need to find the right inputSetItem in `_inputSetItems` and update that item. I dont know what an inputSetItem exactly is but you need to put an identifier on it somewhere, maybe you can use the Tag-property. Then it would look like the following:

`private void generateRandomGuid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var delBal =  _inputSetItems.First(_ => _.Tag == "balanceIdentifierSet");
        Guid randomGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        //delBal.btn_Guid.Input = randomGuid.ToString();
        delBal.Input.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    }`

Answer (score 0):

So figured it out.

I had to create a Control instances

```
   private Control _idemp;
```

Add the textbox assigning it

```
var IdempotencyRef = InputGenerator.GenerateInputControl(this, typeof(Guid), "IdempotencyReference");
            _idemp = IdempotencyRef.Input;
            Controls.Add(IdempotencyRef.Label);
            Controls.Add(_idemp);
```

And then updating the method

```
private void generateRandomGuid(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid randomGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            _idemp.Text = randomGuid.ToString();

        }
```